# Get text nested inside JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, azure-cognitive-services

I have learning JSON for a week. When I try to use Cognitive Services, it returned JSON format to the output. It very complicated to see for the user. So I just want to take some attribute of it to display on screen. But when I try to access nested attribute inside it, even with comma or brackets, it still not work! I just want to take out "text" attribute and plus it to string.

```
{
  "language": "en",
  "orientation": "Up",
  "textAngle": 0,
  "regions": [
    {
      "boundingBox": "12,106,781,327",
      "lines": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "52,106,230,35",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "52,108,44,33",
              "text": "60"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "110,106,172,35",
              "text": "Beautiful"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "29,166,276,42",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "29,166,99,35",
              "text": "Good"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "141,166,164,42",
              "text": "Morning"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "99,229,134,39",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "99,229,134,39",
              "text": "Images"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "12,301,308,26",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "12,304,20,16",
              "text": "to"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "38,302,52,17",
              "text": "make"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "96,307,44,20",
              "text": "ypur"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "145,301,80,18",
              "text": "timeline"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "231,307,89,12",
              "text": "awesome"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "589,417,204,16",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "589,417,204,16",
              "text": "www.birthdaywishes.expert"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Which text attribute? All of them joined? An array? `it still not work` - post your code then

Comment: It kind of get all "text" attribute and make it a sentence like in my example:  "text": "60" + "text": "Beautiful" + "text": "Good" + "text": "Morning" into a string to output to screen: 60 Beautiful Good Morning....

Comment: I think you'll have to loop over and concat the `text` property into a single string. Shouldn't be that difficult, did you try anything yourself? Please add that code into your question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to flatten the object and print the text from it.

```
var obj = {


"language": "en",
  "orientation": "Up",
  "textAngle": 0,
  "regions": [
    {
      "boundingBox": "12,106,781,327",
      "lines": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "52,106,230,35",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "52,108,44,33",
              "text": "60"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "110,106,172,35",
              "text": "Beautiful"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "29,166,276,42",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "29,166,99,35",
              "text": "Good"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "141,166,164,42",
              "text": "Morning"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "99,229,134,39",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "99,229,134,39",
              "text": "Images"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "12,301,308,26",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "12,304,20,16",
              "text": "to"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "38,302,52,17",
              "text": "make"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "96,307,44,20",
              "text": "ypur"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "145,301,80,18",
              "text": "timeline"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "231,307,89,12",
              "text": "awesome"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "589,417,204,16",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "589,417,204,16",
              "text": "www.birthdaywishes.expert"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

let textArray = [];
let str = '';

obj.regions.map(region => region.lines.map(line => line.words.map(word => textArray.push(word.text))));

textArray.map(val =>{
    str = str + val + ' ';
})

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Thanks @Mahipal. My way is using dot and bracket for each text but it so noobs. Thank you so much!

Comment: `.map` is definitely not the appropriate method to use, since you aren't creating a new array. If you want to iterate over an array and produce a single value at the end, use `reduce` (or if you don't know `reduce`, then `forEach` - but not `map`, since you aren't using the mapped array)

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes that definitely can be done. Thanks for the suggesion. all the `map()` can be replaced by `forEach()` in the solution which i mentioned inorder to not create the new arrays.